# Pages for iOS won't let me insert or replace pictures (images)

Tags: ios, pages

When i click on the "insert stuff" button, the window pops up with the tabs that let me pick pictures, shapes, tables, etc.

If I select a table, shape, or anything but a picture, I can pick a specific one, and it appears in the doc, as it should.  But if i pick pictures, I get to pick from my albums, images, etc, but when I select one, nothing happens - the thumbnail gets darker to reflect that I clicked it, but the app just hangs - no image appears in the doc.

The same thing occurs if I use a pre-made template with a pic in it - I can click on the embedded image icon, and get to my images to pick one to select the generic one, but nothing happens when I pick one.

Any ideas?   I already tried a reset.

Comment: I've had this issue too. I think it has to do with file size and formats. I've circumvented this (sometimes) by going into the photos application and copying the photo I want and then pasting it into Keynote.

Answer (score 1):

Either Pages can't read the type of image file you are trying to use, or there will be a bug fix in later update. Try holding your'e finger over the screen and moving it about, the image might be there just pulling a little trick on you.

Answer (score -3):

Another possibility is a corrupted plist file. Quit Pages.
Go to Preferences in your Library folder and delete com.apple.iWork.Pages.plist and relaunch Pages.

Comment: Topic is Pages on iOS...

Comment: You do know this is tagged iOS, not OS X right? Please read the question lest you do this.